# Not loading CSS and JS ngBoilerplate

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ngboilerplate

I am new to AngularJS and I am using ngBoilerplate project for start.

```
.....
  <!-- compiled CSS --><% styles.forEach( function ( file ) { %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= file %>" /><% }); %>

  <!-- compiled JavaScript --><% scripts.forEach( function ( file ) { %>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= file %>"></script><% }); %>
.....
```

This is how my "index.html" look and I have all of the needed JS and CSS in "vendor" folder.
But in the browser I end up with :

[image]

and an error in the console and as you can assume the JS and CSS are not loaded. Can someone give me an advice what to do ?

Comment: Did you run `grunt watch` at the end? If you did it, you should end up with `build/index.html` that doesn't contain those `<%=...%>` templates anymore.

Comment: Yes I have, that is what has been bothering me. Because the grunt watch does not give any errors and it ends with :

"Running "index:build" (index) task
Running "delta" task
Waiting..."  which is OK I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED IT !

I just have been set Apache configuration (#DocumentRoot and #< Directory .. > ) to  .../myProjectClient/src (where there is an index.html) NOT TO .../myProjectClient/build where is the index.html with the generated sripts and links....